# External file python - writting to external text file

Tags: python, external, word-wrap

I am having a problem with my python code,

```
print("Your memeory size is",memory)
while not any(words in problem for words in ListProb):
    problem = input ("Explain what is wrong with your phone to get the most accurate answer you should use the keywords at the bottom left.")
    case = str(random.randint(1,10000))
    print ("Thank you " + name + " for your information.  We can not solve this for you at the minute.  We will pass on your infomation to our tecnician and get back to you soon.  Your case number is "+ str(case) + ".  Thanks.")
    file = open('Case_data_file ' + case + '.txt','a')
    file.write("Client name:                       " + name + "\n" + "\n" + "Phone model:                       " + model + "\n" + "Memory size:                       " + memory + "\n" + "Your allocated case number:        " + str(case) + "Phone Problem:                     " + problem + "\n")
    file.close()
    exit()
```

the following error is coming up.

> TypeError:’_io.TextWrapper’ object is not callable

Any ideas?

Comment: stacktrace please.

Comment: add your error.So that others can help you

Comment: the error is TypeError 'io.TextIOWrapper' object is not callable this error comes up on the file = open('Case_data_file ' + case + '.txt','a')

Comment: Here is my full code